# Match the column heading and print the values of the column using awk

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, awk

I have a data in the file in columns. I want to write a script, which displays the data of the column matching the column heading.

```
C-1 C-2 C-3 C-4 C-5 C-6 C-7 C-8 C-9
10  30  35  20  9   65  87  30  29
40  32  67  78  30  54  24  21  13
50  43  32  12  43  65  78  67  54
```

if the user choose to display C-8 column then the out put must be

```
C-8
30
21
67
```

I am not sure how to match the column name and print the output using awk.

Thanks,
KJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script for example called `script.sh` with this:

```
awk -v COLT=$1 '
        NR==1 {
                for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                        if ($i==COLT) {
                                title=i;
                                print $i;
                        }
                }
        }
        NR>1 {
                if (i=title) {
                        print $i;
                }
        }
' file
```

Where `file` is the file with the data in columns.

If you issue `script.sh C-8` then the result will be:

```
C-8
30
21
67
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works perfectly. Can you please explain what "column=${column:(-1)}" is working.

Comment: Takes the last character of variable `column`

Comment: I made a change to use the *title column` instead of a number

Comment: This works fine if the column numbers are matching what if the column numbers does not match and column name are some text like name, Rollno, this script will not work in that case.

Comment: If there is not maching, it shows nothing. If text on column is like *Rollno* for example, change variable `to_remove` on the script.

Comment: This is not working, I am getting complete table as the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24909/discussion-between-jcbermu-and-kumarjohn).

Comment: I am trying to enter the chat but its taking time

Comment: @KumarJohn Now you can use any name you want.

Answer (score 1):

Without `awk`, you can use the following command:

```
cut $FILE -f `head -1 $FILE | tr "\t" "\n" | grep -n "^$COLUMNTITLE"'$' | cut -f 1 -d :`
```

Works only if there is a single column matching the exact `$COLUMNTITLE`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
function proj() {
    awk -v c="$1" 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==c) break} {print $i}' "$2"
}
```

Use it like:

```
proj C-8 table.txt
```

If you expect to pass in column names which are not present in the table you should check that: add `i!=NF+1` before `{print $i}`, otherwise you'll get as many empty lines as the rows of the table.

You can also put it in a separate file instead using a function.